# Branding change in published app not reflecting properly when sideloading the updated app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've one msteams bot which sends notifications to users who are on our platform. I've to change the appname(10xGoals -> PeopleCues) and logo name for this app. But when I'm trying to sideload app on a developer account on msteams, still old name is coming at some places. Old name is 10xGoals. New name is PeopleCues. Attaching pic for the reference. Where else shall I make change to reflect the PeopleCues name everywhere? [image]

Comment: We tried to repro the scenario and also faced similar issue. After sideloading the bot app, the updated name is not rendering properly. Attaching screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfP8H.png

Comment: We have raised a bug for the same and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get any further update. Thanks!

Comment: We got update from engineering team that "The bot name on the chat message is pulled from bot registration portal, not from manifest. Please remember to change the name on the bot registration portal and then you'll find it changed here. "